# How to browse Google play store for Android TV without a ATV device?

Tags: google-play-store, android-tv

Can we browse google play store for android TV on web? I know for example these two links but these are not comprehensive in any way!

- [List of apps (partial!)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/promotion_3000e26_androidtv_apps_all)
- [List of games (partial!)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/collection/promotion_3000e24_androidtv_games_all)

I don't have a ATV device (like Mi box , etc) and I need to browse the catalog.

**UPDATE 1:**

I set the user agent to a TV browser (Firefox for Fire TV in [this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent/Firefox)) and visited the store link, but no effect!

https://play.google.com/store/apps/

Comment: Please see the update @kirodge

Comment: Ok, changing the user agent doesn't seem to work (and that was what I actually meant when I wrote "http referrer") . I currently have no other idea. It seems that to get the same experience as on the ATV device you probably would need to edit build props (requires root and may break your device). By using privacy mode in a browser and just searching for "Android TV Games" in google play web store you can at least get a longer list https://play.google.com/store/search?q=android%20tv%20games&hl=en_US